# How do I dismount from my Slime Mount?

Tags: terraria

Cannot get off of this slime mount! I can't get in my house! Please help me!
The only way that I found out that works is going on a Minecart. It gets annoying though.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>R</kbd> is the default mount/unmount key for whatever is in your mount equipment slot.

It sounds like you're finding out by trial and error.  Not certain how it would work if you put it in a hotbar slot.  At a guess, that's what you've done, or you've just activated it by "using" like any other item.

Answer (score 3):

As @Radhil says, <kbd>R</kbd> is the default key to mount/unmount a mount in your inventory or mount equipment slot. Mounts in the mount equipment slot will be prioritised over those in the general inventory.

In addition, you can unmount by right clicking the icon for your mount under the hotbar, since mounts are counted as unlimited buffs. Using a grappling hook or dying will also unmount.

Note that if you have your mount item in the hotbar, you can only use it from there to mount, not to unmount.